# Prevent commits without PR but allow admins to merge without approval

Tags: github, branch, pull-request, git-commit

As the title says, how can I force all commits to require a Pull Request (for admins and non-admins) with 1 approval required (for non-admins only)?

See image below:

[image]

Comment: I don't think even Enterprise custom repository roles let you do that; you could add an Actions workflow that checks the permissions of the authors, and if they aren't admins, only pass if there's a PR approval.

Comment: interesting solution @BenjaminW.! what would be the trigger event for PRs that don't get approved until hours/days later?

Comment: Actually are you suggesting something like this ? https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/collaborating-on-repositories-with-code-quality-features/about-status-checks

Comment: You'd have to trigger the action when the pull request is created (or reopened), on the `pull_request` event, and every time a review is submitted, using the `pull_request_review` event. The result of a workflow can be used as a status check.